# All fonts on Xubuntu are now boxes. Everything is illegible. Help

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, fonts

As in the title, all of Xubuntu is now not characters, just like vertical rectangular boxes, like it cant find the right font.

I am on Xubuntu 14.04

All was normal. Until I tried to add new fonts to GIMP.. I added fonts to `/usr/share/fonts/trutype` and didnt see them in gimp, so I started to just copy the NEW file folders I downloaded from google fonts into some other folders. One was `/home/username/.fonts` and still no updates in gimp , so I rebooted to see if that made the font appear and now the entire GUI interface has no characters and everything is empty rectangular boxes. And I mean everything. File manager, applications like Gimp are all illegible. I can only open and close due to memory of the button and menu locations.

I am able to run the browser and it is fine menu and all text is legible, its just seems like the xfce GUI that is messed up. I would rather get advice from experts than play with it any further. I'm not sure how just copying files to a folder could do this.

I did also install a font viewer app yesterday but it didn't do any good and could not install fonts like I expected. but now I can not even search for it to uninstall.

Has anyone seen this before or know how to solve or where to start?

UPDATE: I was able to remove the app I added, which was font-manager using the command line and apt-get --purge font-manager. I rebooted and same boxes everywhere. I also removed the .font.conf file which was present and  linking to `/home/norman/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`.  Still boxes are present after reboot.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest, if you haven't already, is removing the `~/.fonts` folder completely and reboot.

Comment: that did not work, same boxes. I did notice that this file exist: .fonts.conf -> /home/norman/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf

Comment: So what does that file contain? (You can safely remove the whole `~/.config/fontconfig` folder, since it's user specific, and not part of the default configuration.)

Comment: @GunnarH I deleted this fontconfig director and still boxes after reboot. I also logged off and back on as guest and thee wee boxes, so it seems like more than the user. Again, all i did was copy like 14 font folders into like 3 places where i thought font files should go /usr/share/fonts/trutype and /home/norman/.fonts thats about it. and install and remove the app font-manager

Comment: I saw somewhere someone said they had same issue and got the fonts back by removing the files from /usr/share/fonts/truetype. and it worked!!! instantly all the system files are not characters, BUT, they all look a little different, even the terminal fonts changed. So now, how do I get em back to normal?? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you now have reset `/usr/share/fonts` to its original state, you may want to try these steps:

1. Remove the `~/.cache/fontconfig` folder.
2. Run the command `sudo fc-cache -fr`

   (it will take a while to complete)
3. Reboot.