# Restoring fonts after PlayOnLinux install

Tags: wine, fonts, playonlinux

I installed PlayOnLinux and decided I really didn't need it after installing it. I ran `apt purge playonlinux` after removing the one game I had installed. I rebooted and now my fontawesome fonts have gone weird.

[image]

I have tried:

- Purging `ttf-mscorefonts-installed`
- Removing the `.playonlinux` directory which contained font files as exe.
- Refreshing the font cache
- Rebooting after each process

Any tips on restoring the fonts? Thanks in advance.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with i3. Fontawesome fonts are installed in my `~/.fonts/` directory

Comment: Possibly the steps in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/841789) would help.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No luck