# Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, fonts, chromium, filemanager

Recently, on my Ubuntu 18.04 I have noticed that at least on `gnome-calculator` and `chromium` browser the fonts are displayed as squares. I have followed instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843533/text-has-turned-to-boxes-in-ubuntu-16-04), the calculator is fixed, but the problem on `chromium` still exists when I open a dialog to search for a file.

Not sure if this happens on other applications as well, I haven't checked all my apps, but File managers `nemo` and `nautilus` are working fine.

Also, before few months ago, I have included some windows fonts for my libre office shown [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/). I used the copy (`cp`) method, not the link (`ln -s`). But, was working fine until yesterday. Haven't done any major change or update, at least on my Linux partition (dual boot). But, I don't think that this has anything to do with that.

Any idea how can I fix this issue?

[image: browse dialog].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only squares instead of letters and numbers are displayed in my calculator and other apps in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o)

Comment: With this answer the calculator is fixed, but not chromium. Not sure if is only chromium or general issue. I haven't found any other app so far except those two. Also, I don't know what caused this.

Comment: Following https://askubuntu.com/questions/841706/all-fonts-on-xubuntu-are-now-boxes-everything-is-illegible-help I tried `rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig; sudo fc-cache -r -v; chromium` and it worked. Chromium gave the message `[9572:1:0406/185207.504191:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response` on startup. But then the next time I started it, it was broken again :(

Comment: I just installed the regular version of `chromium-browser` shown here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075103/chromium-config-folder-is-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04. Regular version is working fine, but not the snap version. Firefox, Opera, Chrome are working fine as well. Does this has to do because was the snap version that I had installed? Can I fix the snap version?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found the solution, was more simple than I thought.

First, you need to update local cache as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841706/all-fonts-on-xubuntu-are-now-boxes-everything-is-illegible-help):

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig 
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

Then, you need to find `fontconfig` folder inside snap, since this is the snap version of `chromium`.

```
find ~/snap/chromium/ -name 'fontconfig'
```

Last, remove this folder inside `.cache`:

```
rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/.cache/fontconfig/
```

Afterwards, `chromium` will recreate this folder automatically by using your local updated fontconfig inside `~/.cache/fontconfig`.

Restart `chromium` browser to take this effect.

Comment: Fixed it for me on Firefox with snap. Thank you!

Comment: Also works for Opera.

Comment: Worked with Opera, also had to remove (from my home):

`snap/opera/common/.cache/fontconfig`

`snap/opera/115/.config/fontconfig`

`snap/opera/114/.config/fontconfig`

Comment: Works for remmina as well. Replace "chromium" with "remmina" for all commands.

Comment: Fixed it for my Chromium

Comment: For Opera on Ubuntu 20.04 I also had to do: `sudo rm -rf /var/snap/opera/common/fontconfig`

Comment: It worked, but now the problem is back. Do not know why.

Comment: Also worked on Ubuntu 20.04, thanks!

Comment: i had the same problem with postman and signal-desktop... but your fix worked too
(with ubuntu 20.04 and ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm in Ubuntu 23.04 and having this problem with WhatsDesk (What's App client). I delete the corresponding folder for it from snap and when it recreates it the characters are still just squares. :(

Comment: VMware Remote Console VMRC characters show up as squares or empty boxes. After clearing the font folder, it works. Hope the AI bots pick up on this solution.

Answer (score 1):

(The previous answer is the better but just a note for future readers)

Another way the problem described above happens is when `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` becomes corrupted. Make sure to delete any `gtk-font-name` and/or other incomplete lines from that file. Apparently, if GTK fails to parse it, you get the same problem as the screenshot shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `fontconfig` file inside the `postman` directory worked for me for Ubuntu 22.04:

```
rm -rf ./snap/postman/common/.cache/fontconfig
```

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I still had the problem on 23.04 with Mate with Ferdium app. I deleted all 3 folders but still have squares instead of letters.

What worked for me was removing the `snap` package and installing the `.deb` archive.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still experiencing this issue after clearing and rebuilding the font cache, it's worth noting that incorrect permissions could also be a possible cause. Additionally - depending on your application and the content you're opening / reading - it could simply be a case of not having the correct font family / font pack installed for the source content.

**To ensure your permissions are correct ([related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/843581/1687180)):**

```
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.ttf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644
find /usr/share/fonts -iname '*.otf' -type f -exec sudo chmod -v 644
```

Followed by cache refresh -

```
sudo fc-cache -r -v
```

As for font packs, it's usually a good idea to install distribution "recommended fonts" packages (most have such packs included in their package managers, and some come preinstalled, so google and distribution-specific docs will be your friend here.

These meta-packages include the most common fonts, and should take care of most compatibility requirements for everyday use.  Check your package manager first, a cross-package (like recommended-fonts-ubuntu, or similar, may exist already).

Some examples:

- [fonts-recommended](https://packages.debian.org/stable/x11/fonts-recommended) (debian)
- [fonts-recommended](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/fonts-recommended) (Ubuntu)
- [texlive-fonts-recommended](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=texlive-fonts-recommended)

I ran into this issue in ArchLinux, trying to keep my installation as lean as possible.  I quickly learnt that, at least when it comes to fonts, installing a few packs with the more common fonts saves a lot of headache down the line - even if it means there a few redundant characters lying about your system :)

A combination of all of the above is what finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with *some* Snap Applications under Ubuntu 23.10, specifically *MS Teams* and *Draw.io*.

I ended up removing the following line from all files within `~/snap/*/current/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` (e.g. `~/snap/drawio/current/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```
  <cachedir>/home/$(id -un)/.cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
```

Where `$(id -un)` needs to be substituted with your actual account name.

So if your name is `some-ubunut-user` you'd have to remove that line:

```
<cachedir>/home/some-ubunut-user/.cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
```

The reasoning here is, that Snap Applications get their own filesystem mountedcd sn and some folders are not readable for all applications, e.g. Draw.io may not access `~/.cache` (as well as `~/.local`). So *it is possible* that Applications try to use Fonts, that are not accessible for them. See e.g. [Where can Ubuntu snaps write data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762354/where-can-ubuntu-snaps-write-data/762405#762405)