# Snap store doesn't show text

Tags: fonts, 19.10, snap

I've just installed Snap Store on my Ubuntu 19.10.
I am confronting this problem.

[image]

I have checked the font used in my system, it is the default font.
And my system language is set to English(United States)

[image]

I don't know why this happens. Could anyone help fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Yes, I have tried rebooting, the problem still persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @karel That doesn't answer my question because my font is generally American English. It is not Chinese or any special fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Close the snap store and run these two commands:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
```

```
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```bash
fc-cache -r
```