# After update to ubuntu 20.04 problems with displaying characters

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, locale

```bsh
  locale 
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
  LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"   
  LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"   
  LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"   
  LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"   
  LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"   
  LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2YaN.png)

Comment: Maybe this topic may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks for answer!  
It turned out to be faster to reinstall ubuntu than to find a solution)