# /home partition shows corrupted characters after Ubuntu Studio 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, home-directory, ubuntu-studio

**Background:**

Ubuntu Studio 19.10, upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS using bootable USB and "Install Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS" option.  The system has an SSD `/dev/sda` and HDD `/dev/sdb` with partitions `/dev/sda2` scratch formatted as ext4 with mount point `/` and  `/dev/sdb2` previously formatted as ext4 with mount point `/home`.

I chose to reformat `/dev/sda2` as ext4 and to mount the existing `/dev/sdb2` on the `/home` directory.  This is the same setup used in previous Ubuntu Studio upgrades without unexpected issues.

**The result:**

The system seems to start normally enough and the desktop appears with the icons and their locations correct.  The text characters, however, look like white rectangular outlines with tiny white circles inside (similar to a domino block outline) and they fail to execute with the errors also containing the similar characters.

Perhaps this is because of a character corruption.  Maybe this is a simple matter of character formatting.

Are any users familiar with this issue that could offer some pointers?

Comment: In general, the way to upgrade is to use the existing upgrade scripts from within the previous distribution. That's not to say this shouldn't work, so hopefully someone can help you solve this problem.

Comment: Fresh install while keeping existing home directory should always work (which is what OP is doing)

Comment: Check this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04?r=SearchResults

Comment: The small 'domino' outlines turned out to contain ascii numbers, such as '0 0 6 5', which is the ascii number for 'e'.  There are lots of font definition files under '/usr/share/fonts'.  '/usr/local/share/fonts' and '~/.local/share/font-manager/Library' were empty, while '~/.fonts' had a link to the empty '~/.local/share/font-manager/Library' and a 'Read Me.txt' file.  I copied ttf files to '~/.fonts' and the empties mentioned.  No luck.  Will continue to try and get this right for a while.