# Nautilus "Select File" window invalid characters (□□□) on some snap applications (Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome)

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, fonts, electron

[image]

Some applications downloaded from the Snap store, appear like this when I select to open a file. Other applications, such as Chromium, don't. This screenshot, in particular, is from Discord.

I reinstalled the snap application and the same thing happened, only difference that my GTK theme was not applied, so I had to run `sudo snap connect application-name:gtk-3-themes qogir-themes:gtk-3-themes`.

I have set a custom font via the Gnome Tweaks application, could that be the issue? Here is my neofetch: [image]

This is how it looks when I open a file on Chromium:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this? Is it an issue with my theme/font (Whitney Medium) exclusively?

EDIT: I have found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9616) and suspect the issue might be with the Electron platform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @vanadium Unfortunately that did not help. That question seems to be more specific the cache in the Chromium browser (and people report it also worked for other browsers). For me, Chromium is just fine. Software like Sublime Text and Electron Player also worked fine. At this time I have only identified that this issue occurs for Discord and Caprine (Messenger).

Comment: It is for these specific apps that you need to have the font cache recreated.

Comment: Check my edit. I have found that this is a bug with the Electron platform. The issue I linked does not describe at all how it is fixed but claims that it has somehow been resolved in their "latest" version. I am currently contacting the developers of both Discord and Caprine to inform them.

Comment: I agree, I have retracted the close vote.