# Some language letters are empty squares

Tags: lubuntu, fonts

In my Lubuntu 18.04 Armenian letters are not displaying at all, not in system nor in browser. I had Lubuntu 18.04 before, and everything was ok, I think my previous lubuntu had another subversion.
Tried to clear font caches, but no result.
Please note that Lubuntu is fresh installed. I need solution ASAP, because today will demo of my project and whole website is in squares.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses  See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note only supported releases are on-topic here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @pLumo No, I tried that solution a few days ago. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what helped me, but issue is fixed. Thanks every one.