# Whatsapp attach screen unreadable characters

Tags: lts, whatsapp

I would like to attach a .pdf file and get a screen with rectangles.
How to fix it?
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Thank you.[image]

Comment: Is this the same problem you had days ago with Skype? Are you sure you installed the additional fonts, accepting the license and all? What are you using here for Whatsapp, the web version or some (unofficial) client, which one?

Comment: Additional question: Can you open the PDF normally and is it readable? What language(s) / alphabet(s) should be there?

Comment: A PDF file opens without any problem. I got Whatsapp from Ubuntu Software (WhatsApp for linux (unofficial)). Before WhatsApp for linux I had whatsdesk, and it was fine. Probably it was updated and after that I have this issue.Yes, I did have the same problem with Skype but now it's OK.The Unicode font is there. I tried to take the same steps as for Skype but it does not help.

Comment: I ran it from terminal and got the following output:`$ whatsdesk
/bin/sh: 1: update-alternatives: Permission denied

(whatsdesk:12130): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:25:43.750: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1566:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(whatsdesk:12130): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:25:43.755: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3618:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(whatsdesk:12130): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:25:43.756: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4080:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name`

Comment: look this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04
change chromiun and use whatsdesk /kesty
It works

Comment: You can resolve this issue by installing the 22.04 fonts.
It worked for me! :-) https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/04/restore-old-fonts-ubuntu-2304/