# Android-x86 9.0-R2 Pie for VirtualBox (6.1) image from OSB on Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't show font/text in Instagram app

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, android

Does somebody know what's up with it? I see squares instead of text.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Hi, did you fix this? I have the same issue but I'm not using Ubuntu (I'm on Gentoo).
Obviously previous comment is completely unrelated. First this isn't Ubuntu but android-x86, then it's not a chartype issue rather like a bad bold font.

Comment: @Stopi no. I haven't fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. I tried all kinds of resolutions and DPI settings nothing worked. Then I installed Instagram Lite and it doesn't make the square text.