# All square icon while uploading file in postman

Tags: updates, icons, filemanager, 23.04

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04. facing an issue while uploading a file in postman, unable to see the proper icon.

[image: img]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04)