XMind Snap latest/stable 24.1.14361 - Fonts not rendering in export file window
I've recently installed xMind on Ubuntu 24.04 and found a rather strange problem i've not encountered before using other Snap software. When trying to export a map as .png the file browser to save the file has no text just rectangular boxes. I have attempt to remove the font-cache with fc-cache -r but this doesn't seem to have worked in this case.
Running the program from a terminal gives a few more clues with this error;
[I 2024-06-05T15:05:44.174Z fonts] start get system fonts
[W 2024-06-05T15:05:44.230Z fonts] Error on doGetFontPaths [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/share/fonts/cMap/Identity-UTF16-H'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/usr/share/fonts/cMap/Identity-UTF16-H'
}
[W 2024-06-05T15:05:44.231Z fonts] Error on doGetFontPaths [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/share/fonts/cmap/Identity-H'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/usr/share/fonts/cmap/Identity-H'
}

I'm at a loss where to go from here. Has anyone else had this error and fixed it or can point me in the right direction.

This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04
