# None of the characters visible in any window of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, fonts, gnome-shell, bug-reporting

I updated from 16.04. All files were downloaded, but after installation for several hours(almost all were installed), update manager froze of about 3 hours. I killed the upgrade manager and rebooted. Now it starts in ubuntu 18.04, but none of the characters are visible as shown in image below:

[image]

even the command line is not visible:

[image]

Only xterm is visible. Chrome is also working fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text has turned to boxes in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843533/text-has-turned-to-boxes-in-ubuntu-16-04) See first answer!

Comment: Try this first: it does not involve changing permissions of system files: https://askubuntu.com/questions/841706/all-fonts-on-xubuntu-are-now-boxes-everything-is-illegible-help

Comment: @digijay `fc-cache -fr` worked! Thanks.